# Get-RDUserSession not executing in PSScript when called

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I have a PSScript that I call from C#. The problem that I am encountering, is that even though script has loaded, the Get-RDUserSession is not being executed. The function which contains this cmdlet is being called, because if I include the Get-Process, I am getting results.

Therefore, I am at a loss as to why and how I get this particular cmdlet to execute from C# - it works in Powershell directly.

My code is:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
     ps.Runspace = rs;
     ps.AddScript(myscript);
     ps.Invoke();
     ps.AddCommand("MyFunction");
     Collection<PSObject> output = ps.Invoke();
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your C# Object is set correctly to either 64bit or 32bit depending upon your environment.